# jquery preventdefault not working on a tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the preventdefault method but for some odd reason, it does not work.

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="upload-own bold">Upload your own here</a>

$("a#upload-own").on("click", function (e) {    
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: I am using preventdefault elsewhere in my script with no problem.

I have checked several links here on SO and really don't see a wrong thing  in what I did
Is there anything wrong in the way am using for this context?

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? e.preventDefault just prevents the browser to navigate to the link.

Comment: Yes Pol but it still redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your 'a' element has an id with a Space in it. That's not valid html. Then your selector can't find the element!

Comment: Yes you re right. That was initially a class and then I had changed to id but forgot about the details you just showed. Appreciate the support